# Borders show up on load then disappear once the page is fully loaded

Tags: html, border, jquery-ui-tabs

I am working on a website. One of its page shows up borders above and under jquery tabs on load, then they disappear when the page is fully loaded.

> `http://174.122.149.60/~alibakht/wedding-planner-dubai/`

I couldn't find any borders in the code and i reset all the borders to 0 before.

Can please take a look and advise?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question; do not expect people to click through to your site to investigate it. It may also be a good idea to create an example on a site like jsfiddle or jsbin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is here:

```
.fb-like-box { /* Line 192 in style.css */
padding-top: 15px;
border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.fb-like { /* Line 197 in style.css */
padding-top: 15px;
border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Just load the Site without JS to locate the elements ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of visibility css use jquerys default show()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#navtab').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tabs').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Try the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#navtab').show();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tabs').show();
});
```